# How to determine the software version of an RPC node?

Tags: rpc

If I connect to a remote RPC node, is there a request to determine what release of Monero it is running?

For example, I might prefer an RPC node running v15.0.0 including the recent side channel mitigation.

I have already looked at https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/ but I cant seem to find a request that gives me this information.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the node is not running with the restricted RPC (i.e. `--restricted-rpc`), 
 you can check its version by calling [get_info](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info). E.g.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}'
```

The result object has a version field like: `"version": "0.15.0.1-release"`

Comment: Actually, I tried this already, but it does not work for all nodes. Maybe, I should specify that I am interested mainly in public remote nodes. If you try `curl -X POST http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/get_info` you will see that sometimes you get an output as you quote, but mostly you get `"version": ""`

Comment: I am really confused why there is this difference in response??

Comment: I should have added that only nodes run without `--restricticted-rpc` will show this.

Comment: If you are using a third party's node, its exact version is none of your business. This information is withheld to diminish fingerprinting possibilities (though there's probably a lot that can be used still). Morever, if the node isn't yours, it could well lie. Last, the side channel fixes are wallet side.

Comment: This is true. Here is obviously not the right place for a discussion on it, but, I think we may want to include a major version number that's not restricted. All nodes are expected to be on the same consensus so off the top of my head I don't think it's a privacy issue (especially for public remote nodes). Anyway, yes, wrong place for this discussion!